# Excel shows NOT RESPONDING after running a code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem running this specific macro:

```
Sub Macro2()

    Sheets("FilteredData").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ListObject.ListColumns(1).Delete
    Selection.ListObject.ListColumns(1).Delete
    Selection.ListObject.ListColumns(1).Delete
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

After running this macro, my excel file just freeze. Is there a problem with the macro code? I have been looking around but cant find an answer for this problem :(

Please don't laugh at me for asking this question. I just started exploring macros few hours ago...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whats wrong with your code, if there is anything wrong. But can you try to put this code in place and see if it works better? also i don't think that CutCopyMode can be false/true, i believe that the value has to be integer of 1 or 2

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = Sheets("FilteredData")
    For i = 1 To 3
        If sh.ListObjects(1).ListColumns.Count > 1 Then
            sh.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```